# How am I able to chat inspite of having just 13 rep on Android Stack overflow

Tags: discussion, support

I know that for a user to Chat he must have +20 Rep but me having hardly +13 rep can chat very easily without any restrictions(Participate in a chat and also reply back) .I wonder how is this possible?

In Android Enthusiasts 15 Rep 
In Stack Overflow 54Rep
I am joining the Android chat  Room through Android Enthusiasts so I must not be allowed to interact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's only one chat site for all of Stack Exchange, so you only need to have 20 rep on any SE site to use chat.

The rep limit for chat is more to discourage "smurf" accounts (i.e. established users making a second account just to engage in disruptive behaviour) and spam, rather than to limit chat to knowledgeable users, so this makes sense even if it was an accident of how chat works.

Comment: You mean to say that rep on Chat Overflow is enough to chat in any room irrespective of the rep earned is less

Comment: Yes, your 54 rep on Stack Overflow qualifies you to chat in any room, regardless of which SE site the room is associated with.

Comment: Good thing to know! Makes absolutely sense. I just never thought about that. Thanks (+1) for pointing out!